# UIButton current colour check

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard

I want to check the current colour of the button and if it is blue I want to perform a certain action.

However I have compared it with this way, and it always fails. Even though in storyboard the backgroundcolour is set to system Blue.

How do I check what colour?

What I've done:

```
    @IBAction func myBlueButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.backgroundColor == .systemBlue{
        print("yeah its equal")
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally, you shouldn't need to check a button's colour. Check your _model_ instead. What does a blue button represent in your app?

Comment: @Sweeper Alright, I am new to swift and thought checking colours would be easier. IS checking colours a bad practice?. In my app blue = button is on, and grey = button is off. Based on this, when blue, I send a different api call and when its grey its different from blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, view objects should not save state.

You can distill your question from

"I want to check the current colour of the button and if it is blue I want to perform a certain action"

To:

"I want to check the state of a view object and perform a certain action based on that state."

Don't do that.

Add an entry to your model that tells you information about the state of your feature. Not in terms of "the button is blue" but "we are in edit mode" (or whatever "the button is blue" **means** to your app's business logic.)

(It's a bad idea to make your business logic depend on the visual state of your app.

Imagine you write your app to check the button color and decide app state based on that. A year later, you decide to give your app a facelift, and update your button colors to use a different color theme. Now your active button color is mauve, and inactive is partly transparent black. You make the change, and then for some strange reason your API calls aren't working any more. After waaaaayyyy too much head-scratching, you realize, sheepishly, that your business logic was looking at your view style to determine state. When you changed the styling of your views, it broke your business logic.)